# Обращение к свойству через строку

Tags: c#, property

Возможно вопрос покажется странным но хочется узнать. В таком языке как javascript можно обратиться к свойству объекта через строку к примеру

```
var nameProp = "length";
object.length == object[nameProp]
```

Можно ли подобное реализовать в C#?

Нашел вот такой вариант, но это не то..

```
public class User
{
  int Id {get; set;}
  string Name {get; set;}

  public object this[string propertyName]
  {
    get
    {
      if (propertyName == "Id") return this.Id;
      if (propertyName == "Name") return this.Name;
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**:

Как я почитал, это не лучший способ решить данную проблему, проблема в том: с файла достается большое количество информации и нужно записать ее в объект, но так как свойство довольно много если писать все вручную получиться довольно таки громоздкий код. Как лучше поступить в данной ситуации?

Comment: Чем же это не то? Ну, если отбросить ошибку, из-за которой оно не скомпилится.

Comment: Повтор вопроса [110439](http://hashcode.ru/questions/110439)

Comment: точнее не совсем то,свойств много и для каждого писать, сильно много когда получиться...

Comment: Если объект используется только для хранения информации, почему бы не подумать об использовании `Dictionary<string, TValue>`?

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед, используйте [де]сериализацию.

Comment: @VladD, нет возможности использовать "[де]сериализацию" , а что если использовать Hashtable??

Answer (score 6):

Используйте рефлексию. Хотя советую приостановить работу на минут 15 и подумать, а все ли верно, раз приходится к такому прибегать?

```
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
   return src.GetType( ).GetProperty( propName ).GetValue( src, null );
}
```

Comment: как я почитал это не лучший способ решить данную проблему, проблема в том :
с файла достается большое количество  информации и нужно записать ее в объект, но так как свойство довольно много если писать все вручную получиться довольно таки громоздкий код.
как лучше поступить в данной ситуации?

Comment: Мне кажется что лучше все предусмотреть и парсить файл по заданным правилам. Файлов наверняка еще и много? Тем более неприятно если вдруг какой-либо повредится или был сформирован с ошибкой.

Comment: все ошибки отлавливаются, если произойдет ошибка программа перейдет к следующему файлу.
"Мне кажется что лучше все предусмотреть и парсить файл по заданным правилам."
не совсем понял.

Comment: @decyrus,а что если использовать Hashtable??

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor`

Answer (score 2):

Лучшим и самым правильным решением было бы воспользоваться [де]сериализацией и не переизобретать велосипед.

Для случая, если это невозможно, попробуйте читать данные в `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Рефлексия -- тоже хорошее решение, хотя она, конечно, довольно медленна и громоздка в реализации.

Answer (score 1):

> В таком языке как javascript можно обратиться к свойству объекта через строку
>   Можно ли подобное реализовать в C#?

Можно с помощью [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264736.aspx) и [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6), примерно так:

```
#r "Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
#r "System.Core.dll"

using System.Dynamic;
using System.Collections.Generic;

dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
d.newProp = 123;   // добавили свойство и значение
Console.WriteLine(d.newProp);   // 123
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("; ", (IDictionary<string, object>)d)); // [newProp, 123]
```

Можно перехватывать изменения значений добавленных свойств:

```
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
(d as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += (s,e) => 
    Console.WriteLine("Changed: " + e.PropertyName);
d.newProp = 123;     // в Console выводится "Changed: newProp"
```