# Создание членов-классов на лету

Tags: классы, структуры, c++

Всех с новым годом, господа, и сразу из-под ёлки к делу. Пишу программу, которая будет работать  с несколькими файлами структурированных данных. Забегая на перед, обобщу: по идее должно получиться некое недо-СУБД. До вскрытия файла/таблицы типы и размеры записей/полей неизвестны. Вот пятой точкой чую, что в C++ можно на лету создавать классы и структуры ну или как минимум их члены. Подскажите, как это делается, ну или хотя бы как это называется?

Comment: @Димка, а что на самом деле нужно?

Генерить программы  для эффективной (структуры известны на стадии компиляции) обработки  этих файлов или достаточно просто извлекать "по имени" данные из каждой записи в переменные?

Comment: @avp, делаю карточную онлайн игру. Но в здесь 50% спортивного личного интереса, так, что не спрашивайте почему хранение данных не на готовых СУБД. А теперь суть: необходимо извлекать из файлов упорядоченные данные. Но структура сущностей естественно разная, а хотелось бы для работы с ними написать/использовать один инструмент.  Например, использовать его в другом проекте.

Comment: Логическую структуру файла опишите подробнее (то, что он содержит в т.ч. метаданные -- понятно).

Тогда можно будет придумать что-то кроме общих слов.

Comment: создание свойств/методов/событий  возможно с помощью [dynamic](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/192700/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83/475138#475138) -- но это в C#.

Answer (score 2):

А как потом к этим именам обращаться будете? В с++ все имена переменных и функций должны быть известны на момент компиляции.

Но давайте подумаем, что подобное возможно. И я показал некий синтаксис, который это позволяет сделать. Тогда сразу возникнет ещё пара вопросов. Как узнать список переменных некоторого класса (их имена, количество) и как обращаться к ним по имени. Это конечно частично решается использованием rtti, но будет костыль на костыле. А код будет жуткий. А ещё появиться вопрос в том, как отличать функции/переменные собственные от тех, которые пришли от полей базы.

Поэтому обычно это решают по другому. Делают один класс, у которого есть переменная

```
std::map<string, Field> fields;
```

Узнать кол-во полей просто - это просто список ключей.

А для хранения значений нужно создать специальный абстрактный класс. В с++ нет перегрузки по возвращаемому значению, поэтому нужно создать кучу спецфункций.

```
class Field {
  public
    int getFiledType(); // тут можно и enum использовать
    int getInt(); // возвратить значения поля в виде int
    std::string getString(); // возвратить поле в виде строки
    bool getBool();
    //....
}
```

а в наследниках переопределяем правильно методы. К примеру, класс для строкового поля в функции getString просто возвращает значение, а в getInt либо пытается преобразовать в число, либо просто "бросает исключение". Класс для работы с числовыми полями преобразовать в строку всегда сможет - тут немного легче.
Можно условиться, что getString обязаны реализовать все наследники и не генерировать исключения.

У меня когда то была очень похожая задача. Нужно было генерировать классы на основании json файлов. Я написал скрипт на перл, который читал исходные файлы, делал анализ (угадывал типы полей) и генерировал `.сpp/.h` файлы. В них было много "метаинформации". Поэтому, если мне нужно было получить список всех полей, которые возвращают целое, то я просто доделывал генератор и получал специальную новую функцию, которая возвращала нужный список. Также там было много-много макросов, что бы не было много однотипного кода. Этот скрипт был включен в make файл и все было относительно прозрачно для компилятора.

Comment: Спасибо. Подумаю, поковыряюсь. Ну хотя бы типы и размер данных я сразу заложу в файл и гадать не надо будет.

Comment: @Димка, думаю, на самом деле @KoVadim не угадывал, а *определял* типы данных. Синтаксис json однозначно задает тип поля (только для отделения real от integer требуется просмотреть несколько символов).

Конечно, для дат и т.п. "угадайка" может и потребоваться (но это и не встроенные C++ типы).

Answer (score 1):

Дальнейшие изыскания привели к следующим выяснениям:
1)Моя пятая точка меня подвела.  
2)Запрашиваемое явление именуется "Динамический класс" и в c++ места не имеет. Во всяком случает на прямую реализация вроде как противоречит самой ООП-парадигме языка.
3)"Бубен для программирования" надо помещать в раздел "экзотических игрушек" секс-шопа. Ибо между "кодо-шаманизмом" и "сексом с кодом" я вижу много аналогий.

Comment: @Димка: В C# подобное возможно. Кроме того, существуют весьма облегчающие жизнь фреймворки наподобие Entity Framework или NHibernate. Возможно, вы выбрали неправильный язык для своей задачи.

Comment: Ну если описать задумку в целом, то я разрабатываю онлайн карточную игру. Клиент будет на c#. А вот серверная часть проектируется под линукс. Я сам по профессии php-харь среднего пошиба и конечно же не обладаю широтой знаний вариаций изготовления задуманого, но из имеющегося в голове предположил, что "плюсы" самое оно.  Скорее всего дело не в языке, а в моем знание и умении применять возможности c++. И скорее всего никакой динамический класс не нужен. Соображения уже есть и уже пробую накидать прототип решения.

Comment: Мне кажется, для карточной игры вам не нужна числомолотилка, поэтому возможно вам стоит посмотреть на более высокоуровневые языки. C#, а может быть Python. На них проще писать, чем на C++.