# Обращение к полям класса по имени

Tags: c#

Допустим есть класс

```
class A 
{
    public int Age;
    public string Name;
}
```

Что необходимо сделать чтобы можно инициализировать поля экземпляр класса через `instance["Age"] = 5;`
И возможно ли такое?

Comment: а почему не `public int Age {get;set;}`? и пусть меня поправят у Вас не свойства а поля

Comment: @Bald56rus а в чем разница между полем и простым (тем более автоматическим) свойством? :) Не надо только про инкапсуляцию говорить.

Comment: @andreycha я не знаю ответа:) свойства использую как то на автомате, потому что те примеры которые я видел везде используются свойства, плюсы свойства знаю из этого [ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0/197075#197075)

Comment: @Bald56rus в том же ответе и написано, что разницы нет. Она появляется только тогда, когда нужно над полем навернуть некоторую логику. И вот тут действительно на помощь приходят свойства (как чуть более удобная замена паре методов GetXXX/SetXXX). Так что  если у вас есть простой POCO, полей там более чем достаточно.

Comment: @andreycha а почему тогда не использовать *автоматические свойства* кроме явных случаев когда необходимы *поля*? даже в РОСО?!

Comment: @Bald56rus использовать можно, конечно же. Я лишь говорю о том, что в таком случае это не принципиально, плюс просто больше кода/накладных расходов получается.

Comment: @andreycha на свойство можно поставить брекпойнт. на поле - нет. накладных расходов - одинаково.

Comment: @PashaPash, а зачем может понадобиться ставить брейкпоинт на автоматическое свойство?

Comment: @PashaPash только вот для автоматических свойств брейкпойнт на геттер или сеттер не поставить :). Придется объявлять и использовать backing field.

Comment: @Grundy например, чтобы посмотреть, откуда в объект приходит странное значение.

Comment: @andreycha у меня в студии прекрасно ставятся брекпойнты и на геттеры и на сеттеры. и срабатывают. - http://i.imgur.com/kBQ23SJ.png что я делаю не так?

Comment: @andreycha для старых студий - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6713867/1988244

Comment: @PashaPash не знал такого трюка, спасибо. А в 2015 действительно уже исправили.

Answer (score 12):

Это можно сделать с помощью индексатора (`[]`) и рефлексии. Примерный код:

```
public object this[string fieldName]
{
    get
    {
        var field = this.GetType().GetField(fieldName);
        return field.GetValue(this);
    }
    set
    {
        var field = this.GetType().GetField(fieldName);
        field.SetValue(this, value);
    }
}
```

Данный код работает для всех экземплярных полей. Если вам надо устанавливать в т.ч. и статические поля -- нужно изменить код. Также по-хорошему нужно добавить валидацию (например, что указано имя существующего поля, или что тип устанавливаемого значения соответствует типу поля) и кэширование списка полей (чтобы запрашивать их только один раз).

---

Хотя лучше всего таки использовать сами поля или свойства. Или заменить ваш класс на словарь, где ключом будем являться имя поля/свойства.

Answer (score 1):

> инициализировать поля экземпляр класса через instance["Age"] = 5; И возможно ли такое?

Можно просто написать `instance.Age = 5;`.
Для этого надо использовать `dynamic` и `ExpandoObject`. Пример - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475138/196972).

Answer (score -2):

переопредилить оператор []
что то вроде этого:

```
class a 
{

public int age;
public string name;

public object this[int i]
{

   get { return age[i]; }
    set { age[i] = value; }
}

}
```

Comment: а как вы у `int` представляете `age[i]`?