# Сортировка коллекции по имени поля

Tags: c#

Есть некоторый класс, который содержит большое количество полей (> 50). Есть коллекция, которая содержит элементы этого класса. Нужно реализовать метод, который сортирует эту коллекцию по заданному полю. Поле задается через передачу методу строки с именем нужного поля. При этом к классу позже, возможно, будут еще добавляться поля. Метод должен сортировать коллекцию по новым полям без изменений самого метода. 
Использование IComparer и рефлексии не подходит. Есть ли другой способ получить доступ к полю объекта по его названию?

Уточнение: IComparer  не может быть реализован для самого класса, для типов полей класса сравнение доступно.

Comment: "Использование ... рефлексии не подходит" и "получить доступ к полю объекта по его названию" -Лучше, конечно, помучиться. Тов. Сухов, "Белое Солнце Пустыни"

Comment: Эээ... А кто вам поставил такое задание? Присоединяюсь к предыдущему оратору: вы сами создаёте себе проблемы.

Comment: Почему именно не подходит рефлексия? Если проблема в скорости - то тогда это можно оптимизировать через Reflection.Emit или через Linq.Expressions, будет вообще без оверхеда после первого запуска.

Comment: @ОлегНечитайло можете привести пример использования Expressions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем виде ваша задача не имеет решения даже через рефлексию, поскольку для сортировки нужна гарантия, что типы полей допускают сравнение, т.е. реализуют `IComparable`, тут, увы, альтернатив нет.

При таком количестве полей имеет смысл подумать о замене безумного числа полей на что-то типа `Dictionary<string, IComparable>`. В этом случае вы получаете доступ к значениям по имени, которого вам так не хватает. Плюс, как бонус, можете не расходовать память на хранение "пустых" значений, и безболезненно добавлять любое количество дополнительных именованных значений. При грамотной реализации можно получить очень хорошую производительность. Ну и с методом сортировки сильно мудрить тоже не придется, можете использовать перегрузки стандартных интерфейсов.

Идея подсмотрена [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469682/198316)

Comment: Тоже склонялся к использованию словаря, только не получалось свои мысли воплотить в что то конкретное.